# Convert SQL (Left Outer Join's) to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, linq

I am having trouble converting a Oracle Sql Query with multiple `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to LINQ. My attempts don't return the expected results. Could somebody help to convert the SQL Query below to LINQ.

```
string currentCulture = Culture.GetCulture();
string query = @"SELECT *
               FROM CTGLBL g, CTTGLBL ct, CTLANG lang
               WHERE g.sysctglbl = ct.sysctglbl(+) AND 
                     ct.sysctlang = lang.sysctlang (+) AND
                     NVL(lang.activeflag, 1)= 1 AND
                     (ISOCODE LIKE '" + currentCulture + "%' OR ISOCODE IS NULL)";
```

ISOCODE belongs to CTLANG Table.

ps. I can't use tools like LINQPAD or Linqer.

Comment: `ISOCODE` belongs to what table?

Comment: It belongs to CTLANG

Comment: what are the `(+)` and also this isn't really a right join.... this is a normal join done through where clauses..

Comment: If I am correct it is the old syntax for RIGHT OUTER JOIN: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

Go to Right Outer Join and check the old syntax

Comment: Ah ok - didn't know that syntax

Comment: Yes. With the ISOCODE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120781/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-devid).

Comment: I'd start with re-writing query to use moder, explicit `join` syntax. Then I'd switch from `right join` to `left join`, to feel comfortable. After that I'd feel ready to do the linq transformation.

Comment: Actually this is the old Oracle syntax for **left** outer join.

Comment: @GiladGreen I added some images of the tables in the chat. Hope it makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But a better practice for your sql (and here converted to linq) is to use `join` to join tables and not the `where`:

```
string currentCulture = Culture.GetCulture();

var result = from g in CTGLBL
             join ct in CTTGLBL on g.sysctglbl equals ct.sysctglbl into ctj
             from ct in ctj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join lang in CTLANG on ct.sysctlang equals lang.sysctlang into langj
             from lang in langj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where (lang == null ?  1 : (lang.activeflag ?? 1)) == 1 &&
                 (lang?.ISOCODE.StartsWith(currentCulture) || lang?.ISOCODE == null)
             select new { g, ct, lang };
```

You can also have a `"nested select"` for your `CTLANG` like this:

```
string currentCulture = Culture.GetCulture();

var result = from g in CTGLBL
             join ct in CTTGLBL on g.sysctglbl equals ct.sysctglbl into ctj
             from ct in ctj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join lang in CTTGLBL.Where(lang => lang.activeflag ?? 1 == 1 &&
                                                  (lang.ISOCODE.Contains(currentCulture) ||
                                                   lang.ISOCODE == null))
             on ct.sysctlang equals lang.sysctlang into langj
             from lang in langj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { g, ct, lang };
```

Comment: thanks, will try it out right now. ISOCODE belongs to the table CTLANG.

Comment: thanks I added some images of my tables to the chat. Hope it makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Devid - did it work for you? I had a bug int the first query with the lang == null - now fixed

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY :)  There was just one problem with lang?.ISOCODE (the compiler error was that it can't apply bool? to bool). I did the erased the ? and everything works. Later I will accepts your answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

(What I see is a left join, not right)

Assuming you have the proper relations between the tables in your schema, with SQL server (Linq TO SQL) this would work, not sure if it would supported for Oracle:

```
string currentCulture = Culture.GetCulture();

var data = from g in db.CTGLBL
           from ct in g.CTTGLBL.DefaultIfEmpty()
           from lang in g.CTLANG.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where !g.CTLANG.Any() || 
                 ( lang.activeflag == 1 &&
                   lang.ISOCODE.StartsWith(currentCulture))
           select new {g, ct, lang};
```